# how to print the MAC address

Tags: c++, udp, client-server, ip-address, mac-address

i created a client server program that displays the MAC and ip addresses of the clients and i have a function that gets the MAC address of the computer but I'm having trouble printing the MAC address in a listbox. I created a print function that did work before but i changed the code for finding the mac address and now its not working (also i don't know if i'm calling printMACaddress in the right place). I have two list boxes - one displays the ip address the other displays the MAC address. When i click the ip address i want the MAC address of that computer to be displayed but right now its not displaying. nothing happens when i click the ip address

```
    void CmfcServerDlg::OnLbnSelchangeListClientaddr()
    {
        bool GetMACFromIP(BYTE Address[MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH], const std::string &selected_ip_adr);
    }


    void CmfcServerDlg::PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[])
        {
            CString

 strText;
        strText.Format("%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n",MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
        m_ClientIdList.AddString(strText); 
    }


    bool CmfcServerDlg::GetMACFromIP(BYTE Address[MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH], const std::string &selected_ip_adr)
    {
        IP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo[16];            
        DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterInfo);       

        DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersInfo(           
            AdapterInfo,                            
            &dwBufLen);                             
        assert(dwStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);          

        PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;
        bool found = false;
        do {
            const IP_ADDR_STRING *addr_str = &pAdapterInfo->IpAddressList; 
            while(addr_str != NULL)
            {
              if(selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String) 
              {
                found = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            if(found)
            {
              memcpy(Address, pAdapterInfo->Address, MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH); 
              PrintMACaddress(pAdapterInfo->Address); //problem here
              break;
            }
            else
            {
                PrintMACaddress(pAdapterInfo->Address);
                pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;      
            }
        }
        while(pAdapterInfo);                        
        return found; 
    }
```

Comment: *"I created a print function that did work before but i changed the code for finding the mac address and now its not working"* Why did you change the code for finding the MAC address if it was working?

Comment: because the original code was for only finding the MAC address of the current computer but i am trying to find the MAC address of any computer that connects to the server. I had the old code in the list box event  handler but now i created a separate function for finding the address

Comment: basically the problem is the print function isn't working in the new function i created and i don't know why

Comment: When you used the debugger, what line was the problem?

Comment: i edit the post above. it now includes the event handler for list box which calls the GetMACFromIP function. When i was debugging it skipped the line that calls the function so does that mean its not reading the function?

Comment: can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that your stated goal in the comment ("i am trying to find the MAC address of any computer that connects to the server") is not possible? MAC addresses are lower-level than IP addresses, they identify the "media port", i.e. the place where the cable sits.

You cannot get the MAC address for a client on the other side of a switch even, much less across the Internet.

Comment: i am not using the internet. I am using a UDP connection. The program can work without the internet